# How to read data from url to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to read data from https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ee/ee.industry using pandas, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ee/ee.industry'
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\t')
```

Also tried getting the separator:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ee/ee.industry'
reader = pd.read_csv(url, sep = None, iterator = True)
inferred_sep = reader._engine.data.dialect.delimiter

df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=inferred_sep)
```

However the data is not very weelk formated, the columns of the dataframe are right:

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['industry_code', 'SIC_code', 'publishing_status', 'industry_name'], dtype='object')
```

But the data does not correspond to the columns, it seems all the data is merged into the fisrt two columns and the last two do not have any data.
Any suggestion/idea on a better approach to fet this data?

**EDIT**
The expexted result should be something like:

| industry_code | SIC_code | publishing_status | industry_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000 | N/A | B | Total nonfarm 1 T 1 |

Comment: How do you want your result to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reader works well but you don’t have the right number of columns in your header. You can get the other columns back using `.reset_index()` and then rename the columns:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\t')
>>> n_missing_headers = df.index.nlevels
>>> cols = df.columns.to_list() + [f'col{n}' for n in range(n_missing_headers)]
>>> df.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> df.columns = cols
>>> df.head()
   industry_code SIC_code publishing_status    industry_name  col0 col1  col2
0              0      NaN                 B    Total nonfarm     1    T     1
1           5000      NaN                 A    Total private     1    T     2
2           5100      NaN                 A  Goods-producing     1    T     3
3         100000    10-14                 A           Mining     2    T     4
4         101000       10                 A     Metal mining     3    T     5
```

You can then keep the first 4 columns if you want:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, :-n_missing_headers].head()
   industry_code SIC_code publishing_status    industry_name
0              0      NaN                 B    Total nonfarm
1           5000      NaN                 A    Total private
2           5100      NaN                 A  Goods-producing
3         100000    10-14                 A           Mining
4         101000       10                 A     Metal mining
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice. And any possible way to have it in a generic way? like if instead of 3 extra columns there are 4 or 5

Comment: Sure @Gonca, you always want to keep just 4 columns though?

Comment: That's the issue, it depends of the data. Every dataset has a different number of columns, sometimes it is right with the number of columns but other times, like this, it is not. I can be 4 or more or less, it depends on the dataset

Comment: Great, I think with your last edit itworks great. Thanks a lot

Comment: In this case: https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/bp/bp.measure
Do you know any way I can reand the csv and get the data into 2 columns: `measure_code` and `measure_text` ?